# How to skin clothing/clean up weight painting?

Tags: weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I've got some garments I want to attach to an existing character. I have tried transferring weights from the character to the garments, as well as trying automatic weights on the garments.

I'm not happy with either result. They both need a ton of cleanup. Unfortunately, that's not something I'm good at. I'm very new to weight painting in general.

There are so many vertex groups, and often more than one affects a certain joint, and I'm going back and forth trying to figure what fixes what and how to not overdo it. And sometimes the garments disappear beneath the character mesh and are hard to get to, or sometimes I can't even figure out what is causing bad bending at a certain joint.

Most CG doesn't intimidate me, but this very much does, lol. I feel stumped.

Is there a better way to skin garments? Does anyone have any helpful resources on cleaning up really messed up weight painting jobs? I searched around on YouTube, but didn't have much luck.

Thanks.